# Объясните char* ch = "string"; и компилятор всегда выдаёт ошибку

Tags: c++, строки, указатели, строковый-литерал

Качаю много примеров на С++ и в некоторых местах встречается char* ch = "string"; и компилятор всегда выдаёт ошибку. У меня Visual Strudio 2017 community. Почему так?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char* ch = "test";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Какую ошибку? Как то более подробнее опишите в чем проблема

Comment: Для С++ добавьте `const` -- `const char * = "text";` Дело в том, что указатель и правда ведь ссылается на константу (такие данные нельзя менять, вот компилятор и сообщает об этом)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Насколько я помню, в последних версиях [visual-studio](/questions/tagged/visual-studio), было отменено автоматическое применение `const` к параметрах функций и переменным (локальным), т.е. если вы определили указатель на строку через

```
char* ch = "string" // "string" это не char* а const char*;
```

То, тут по сути должно быть преобразование `const_cast` о котором я говорил выше, которое более не поддерживается и преобразование лежит на разрабртчике.

Comment: Я почему то так и подумал, так как я смотрю ещё разные видео примеры, и на этих видео работают такие записи, а у меня нет. Получается что библиотеки написанные изначально с char* ch не будут работать в новых версиях VS?

Comment: Будут, если вы будете использовать более старую версию MVS. Или установите в параметрах компилятора дополнительный параметр `/-permissive` о котором говорил @Harry. Но лучше так не делать, и просто добавить `const`.

Comment: спасибо нашёл этот флаг заработало, но я буду придерживаться вашего совета в будущем.

Answer (score 4):

Это ошибочное действие, потому что строковый литерал типа `"string"` на самом деле - константная строка, которую нельзя изменять. Она вполне может быть размещена в памяти только для чтения.

А присвоение ее указателю `char*` формально позволяет менять эту строку.

Только вот, к сожалению, VC++ 2017 как раз ни о каких ошибках не сообщает и такое присваивание разрешает :(

Вот, ваша программа при компиляции VC++2017:

```
cl /EHsc /W4 test.cpp

Оптимизирующий компилятор Microsoft (R) C/C++ версии 19.13.26129 для x64
(C) Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corporation).  Все права защищены.

test.cpp
test.cpp(8): warning C4189: ch: локальная переменная инициализирована, но не использована
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.13.26129.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:test.exe 
test.obj
```

Comment: Вот посмотрите пожалуйста https://sun1-2.userapi.com/c840434/v840434080/72940/pksJemv-kDE.jpg

Comment: Вот как раз Visual Studio 2017 о таких ошибках сообщаяет, так как для новых проектов в ней по-умолчанию выставляется флаг `/permissive-`.

Comment: Всё спасибо разобрался